# How get path from custom src subfolder?

Tags: android

In my android project I has structure:

```
src/main
src/main/assets
src/my_custom_folder
src/main/java
src/main/res
```

If I want to get path to `assets` folder I use this:

```
context.getAssets()
```

nice.

But how I can get path to `src/my_custom_folder` ?